# std::cin does not accept input, program closes immediately

Tags: c++, string, input, int, cin

I tried to get a string as an input with `cin` and it worked, but when I tried to get an `int` as an input just after the string the console won't ask for it and the program shuts down. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void main(void)
{ 
string a, b;
int c, d, e;

cout << "Enter two words \n";
cin >> a, b; 
cout << "Enter three int";
cin >> c, d, e;
cout << c*d;
}
```

This code won't let me enter the second input, but I can see the second output before the program shuts down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is wrong:

```
cin >> a, b;
```

will not give you what you expect. In you need to read to strings from `cin`, use:

```
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
```

The same applies for the other types.

Also note that:

```
void main( void )
```

is not correct. `main` **must** return an `int`:

```
int main( void )
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: alright thank you it works! Teacher said we should use void main(void), don't know why.

Comment: You can also do `cin >> a >> b` as stream operators return references to themselves.

Answer (score 3):

The line `cin >> a, b;` uses the comma operator which evalutes the different expressions from left to right. The result is the same as the following code:

```
cin >> a;
b;
```

When the line `cin >> c, d, e;` is reached, it is similarly evaluted as:

```
cin >> c;
d;
e;
```

The result is that when the second `cin >> ...` statement is evaluted the second word you entered is still in the input buffer it completes without waiting for more input from the user.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
cin >> a, b;
```

It should be:

```
cin >> a >> b;
```

Likewise:

```
cin >> c, d, e;
```

should be:

```
cin >> c >> d >> e;
```

Make sure you enable compiler warnings in future - that way the compiler can point out many simple mistakes like this for you. When I compile your original code with warnings enabled I get:

```
$ g++ -Wall junk.cpp
junk.cpp:5:1: error: 'main' must return 'int'
void main(void)
^~~~
int
junk.cpp:13:11: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
cin >> c, d, e;
          ^
junk.cpp:11:11: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
cin >> a, b;
          ^
junk.cpp:13:14: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
cin >> c, d, e;
             ^
3 warnings and 1 error generated.
```

From this it's easy to see that there is something wrong with the two `cin` lines, and that you also need to change the return type of `main` to `int`.

Comment: Great - make sure you turn on those warnings (and take notice of them !).

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
int main(void)
{ 
string a, b;
int c, d, e;

cout << "Enter two words \n";
cin >> a >> b; 
cout << "Enter three int";
cin >> c >> d >> e;
cout << c*d;
}
```